# wrong dates at x axis when plotting POSIXct with scale_x_datetime

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

From the following `dataframe` df:

```
df <- data.frame(Date=as.POSIXct(c("2002-07-01","2002-06-01","2002-05-01","2002-04-01","2002-03-01")),
                 Cat1=c(1,0,1,0,0),
                 Cat2=c(1,1,1,0,0),
                 Cat3=c(0,1,1,0,1),
                 Cat4=c(0,0,1,1,0))

df <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -1)
```

When using `scale_x_datetime` this require `POSIXct` class object, otherwise this complaints with error.

> Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct
> only

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(x = Date, y = factor(name, levels = rev(unique(name))), 
           fill = as.factor(value))) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "grey50")) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.text = element_text(size = 8),
        plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, size =5))+
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 month",
                   labels = scales::date_format("%m-%Y"))
```

With the following input:
[image]

By inspecting the range of `Date` column, this does not match with plot labels from x-axis.

```
range(df$Date)
```

Does anyone how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date` class, and `scale_x_date`

```r
library(ggplot2)

# changing the class by constructing your data differently
df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("2002-07-01","2002-06-01","2002-05-01","2002-04-01","2002-03-01")),
                 Cat1=c(1,0,1,0,0),
                 Cat2=c(1,1,1,0,0),
                 Cat3=c(0,1,1,0,1),
                 Cat4=c(0,0,1,1,0))

df <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -1)

ggplot(df,
       aes(x = Date, y = factor(name, levels = rev(unique(name))), 
           fill = as.factor(value))) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "grey50")) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.text = element_text(size = 8),
        plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, size =5))+
  scale_x_date(labels = scales::date_format("%m-%Y"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @ahbon most likely a missing comma, bracket or plus sign. Review your code, run line by line, and find the bug

Comment: yes, a plus sign is missing. so I'll delete my comment.